# Проблема с интерполяцией кубическими сплайнами

Tags: c++, алгоритм, интерполяция

Мне нужно написать программу для интерполирования ф-ии кубическими сплайнами, но у меня появилась проблема, появление таких вот "ПИКОВ".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <conio.h>

# define M_PI 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884L /* pi */

int N = 6; // розбиение ф-ии
int K = 10; // дополнительное розбиение для "гладкости"

void main() {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 5;
    double h;

    std::string path1 = "D:\\TestFile1.txt";

    double *x = new double[N];
    double *y = new double[N];

    double *x1 = new double[(N - 1) * K + N];

    h = (b - a) / (double)(N - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        x[i] = a + i * h;
        y[i] = sin(x[i] * M_PI) - cos(2.0 * x[i] * M_PI);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ((N - 1) * K + N); i++) {
        x1[i] = a + (i * h) / (K + 1);
    }

    std::ofstream outfile(path1);

    double *y1 = CubicInterpolation(x, y, x1);

    int k = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < (N - 1) * K + N; i++) {
        if (i == k * (K + N)) {
            k++;
        }
        else {
            outfile << x1[i] << " " << y1[i] << "\n";
        }
    }

    outfile.close();

    _getch();

}

double *CubicInterpolation(double *src_x, double *src_y, double *new_x) { // src_x - начальные х, src_y - начальные у, new_x - новые х для нахождения у

    double *H = new double[N - 1];  
    double **gamma = new double*[1];
    *gamma = new double[N - 2];
    double **matrix = new double*[N - 2];
    double *c = new double[N - 2]; // кооф с
    double *d = new double[N - 1]; // кооф d
    double *b = new double[N - 1]; // кооф b
    double *new_y = new double[(N - 1) * K + N]; // массив с выходными значениями
    double *ci = new double[N - 1]; // массив для хранения 0 + все кооф с
    double *a = new double[N - 1]; // кооф а

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new double[N - 2];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) // находим H
    {
        H[i] = src_x[i + 1] - src_x[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++)  // Находим гамму
    {
        gamma[0][i] = 3*((src_y[i + 2] - src_y[i + 1])/(H[i + 1]) - (src_y[i + 1] - src_y[i]) / (H[i]));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N - 2; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) {   // строим матрицу из которой будем находить кооф с
        matrix[i][i] = 2 * (H[i] + H[i + 1]);
        if (i == 0) {
            matrix[i][i + 1] = H[i + 1];
        }
        else {
            if (i + 1 == N - 2) {
                matrix[i][i - 1] = H[i];
            }
            else {
                matrix[i][i + 1] = H[i + 1];
                matrix[i][i - 1] = H[i];
            }
        }
    }

    c = Jordan(matrix, gamma, N - 2); // Решаем матрицу методом Жордана и получаем наши кооф с

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) { // переписываем кооф с в другой массив с добавлнием первого нулевого елемента
        if (i == 0) {
            ci[0] = 0;
        }
        else {
            ci[i] = c[i - 1];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) {  // находим кооф d
        d[i] = ((ci[i + 1] - ci[i]) / 3.0 * H[i]);
    }
    d[N - 2] = (-1 * ci[N - 2]) / (3.0 * H[N - 2]);

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) { // находим кооф b
        b[i] = ((src_y[i + 1] - src_y[i]) / H[i]) - ((ci[i + 1] + 2 * ci[i] / 3.0));
    }
    b[N - 2] = ((src_y[N - 1] - src_y[N - 2] ) / H[N - 2] ) - (2.0 / 3.0)*(ci[N - 2] * H[N - 2]);

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) { // записываем знач а
        a[i] = src_y[i];
    }

    // ф-ия которая проводит интерполяцию, я считаю что проблема где-то в ней 
    for (int k = 0; k < N - 1; k++) {
        for (int i = 1 + k * (K + 1); i < K + 2 + k * (K + 1); i++) {
            new_y[i] = a[k] + (b[k] * (new_x[i] - src_x[k])) + (ci[k] * pow((new_x[i] - src_x[k]), 2)) + (d[k] * pow((new_x[i] - src_x[k]),3));
        }
    }
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ((K + 1) * N - 1); i += K + 1) {
        new_y[i] = src_y[k];
        k++;
    }

    return new_y;
}

double *Jordan(double **a, double **b, int N) {

    double *x = new double[N];

    float R;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (i != k)
            {
                R = a[i][k] / a[k][k];
                for (int j = k; j < N; j++)
                {
                    a[i][j] -= a[k][j] * R;
                }
                b[0][i] -= b[0][k] * R;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        x[i] = b[0][i] / a[i][i];   
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: Для интерполяции известного набора данных, например, y=x^2 на интервале 0..1 получаются коэффициенты, похожие на правду? Почему бы не использовать классический алгоритм из numerical methods, где для СЛАУ используется прогонка (т.к. матрица трёхдиагональная)? Тут, наверное, похожая реализация на шарпе: http://alglib.sources.ru/interpolation/spline3.php#header4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Куча описок, исправьте, проверьте расскажите что вышло:

Скобки прозевали :

```
for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) {  // находим кооф d
        d[i] = ((ci[i + 1] - ci[i]) / 3.0 * H[i]);    }
```

Надо так :

```
for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) {  // находим кооф d
        d[i] = ((ci[i + 1] - ci[i]) / (3.0 * H[i]));    }
```

Опять:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) { // находим кооф b
        b[i] = ((src_y[i + 1] - src_y[i]) / H[i]) - ((ci[i + 1] + 2 * ci[i] / 3.0));    }
```

Надо так :

```
for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) { // находим кооф b
        b[i] = ((src_y[i + 1] - src_y[i]) / H[i]) - (((ci[i + 1] + 2 * ci[i]) / 3.0));    }
```

Comment: Но ведь я интерполирую ф-ию для каждого отрезка x[i + 1] - x[i]

Comment: Тяжёлая задачка. Протестировал Джордана, вроде пашет. Осталось понять логику проги вашей. Плохие имена переменных/массивов, нет функций с именами кто-что делает. А-ля ассемблер.

Comment: Нарисуйте доку: формулы, как / кто должет что сделать(алгоритм).

Comment: да, кончено, вот скриншот алгоритма из методички https://imgur.com/RS7eOpS

Comment: исправьте , проверьте как пашет расскажете/покажете.

Comment: Исправил, стало как-то так: https://imgur.com/a/xHbf1xj

Comment: осталось ещё с **b** повозится : `b[i] = ((src_y[i + 1] - src_y[i]) / H[i]) - (((ci[i + 1] + 2 * ci[i] )/ 3.0))* !! H[i] !!`;

Comment: Да, оно, спасибо большое!

Comment: В формулах каждая скобка очень важна. Дружите с математикой. Удачи.